# asignacion de arrays

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo arrays pero tengo una duda a la ahora de asignarlo, cuando escribo en el input alto, me imprime alto, pero si pongo bajo, me sigue imprimiendo alto, no se como asignarlo.

```
array_numero = ['alto','bajo'] 
nivel = str(input('digite un nivel:'))
 
if nivel in  array_numero:
   print('alto')
elif nivel in  array_numero:
    print('bajo')
else:
    print('No es un nivel de riesgo catalogado')
```

Comment: Buenas Camilo, estoy mirando más o menos lo que quieres decir... pero es que has hecho dos preguntas en una, y a parte, el código mejor ponerlo en formato de código, haz sólo una pregunta o te la van a cerrar

Comment: Cuando escribes alto, la condición se cumple y te imprime lo que has puesto en caso de que se cumpla, pero cuando pones bajo, la condición se vuelve a cumplir, por lo que te vuelve a escribir alto. Te está comprobando dentro de tu array a ver si existen, y existen las dos por lo que se cumple todo el rato la condición

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en estas dos condiciones:

```
if nivel in  array_numero:
    print('alto')
elif nivel in  array_numero:
    print('bajo')
```

Son dos condiciones iguales, y la primera si escribes alto o bajo se va a cumplir, por lo tanto, nunca va a llegar ni a mirar la segunda, creo que te has liado un poco ahí, no necesitas dos condiciones. Lo que creo que has querido hacer es un control de que ponga nivel "alto" o "bajo", y si no escribe ninguno de los dos que le salga que no es un "nivel" válido. Observa:

```
array_numero = ['alto','bajo'] 
nivel = str(input('digite un nivel:'))

# Si el nivel está dentro de los niveles válidos, pintamos el nivel,
# Sino, informamos que no es correcto.
if nivel in  array_numero:
     print(nivel)
else:
     print('No es un nivel de riesgo catalogado')
```

Puedes probar el código y ver que funciona correctamente ahora.

Comment: muchisimas gracias

Comment: nada hombre, si no te importa, dale un votito para arriba y marcala como respuesta, por si alguien se encuentra con un problema parecido, que sepa dónde mirar

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tienes una lista que contiene dos `string` "alto" y "bajo" y una variable `nivel` que recibe un `string` por parte del usuario

En la línea `if nivel in array_numero:` lo que hace es preguntar, ¿Lo que contiene `nivel` existe adentro de la lista `array_numero`? Por lo que si escribes la palabra `alto` o la palabra `bajo` en ambos casos la condición se cumple, porque las dos palabras existen dentro de la lista `array_numero`

Otra cosa, `input` siempre devuelve un `string` por lo que no hace falta que lo  conviertas con `str(input('digite un nivel:'))`

Una forma para hacerlo sería:

```
array_numero = ['alto','bajo'] 
nivel = input('digite un nivel:')
 
if nivel in  array_numero:
    print(nivel)
else:
    print('No es un nivel de riesgo catalogado')
```

Si quisieras comparar directamente con las palabras de tu lista entonces podrías utilizar el índice de las palabras, por ejemplo:

```
array_numero = ['alto','bajo'] 
nivel = input('digite un nivel:')
 
if nivel == array_numero[0]:
    print('alto')
elif nivel == array_numero[1]:
    print('bajo')
else:
    print('No es un nivel de riesgo catalogado')
```

Las listas siempre empiezan con índice `0`, es por eso que `array_numero[0]` contiene "alto"

Comment: muchas gracias pero digamos que si quiero imprimir alto y bajo al tiempo, pongo la funcion split() al final del input?

Comment: Split crearía una lista si ingresaras un `string` con espacios. ¿En qué condición desearías imprimir ambas palabras?